# c# query duration problem including ternary operator in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have quite a difficult query to DB. I am using EF. Query looks like this:

```
bool useSearch = true;

return db.Entity.Where(...)
                .Select(x=> new Model(){ 
                        PropertyA = x.PropertyA, 
                        PropertyB = useSearch ? 0 
                                              : x.PropertyList.where(y=>...).Sum(z=>z.Pieces)
                })
                .ToList();
```

Problem is, that code is about 10 seconds. If i change property `useSearch` to `false`, than still have same time. Does the ternary operator do both conditions in LINQ?

Comment: Probably your `db.Entity.Where(...)` is taking long, did you tried to call that separately?

Comment: How fast is it if you just query the database directly with the same criteria?

Comment: not yet, but false condition sould take much less time than true. Isn´t that?

Comment: i will try, give me few minutes

Comment: time is quite similar

Comment: You should post the contents of where(x=>...) and where(y=>) otherwise we're just guessing

Comment: LINQ queries are translated to SQL queries and then executed. Two causes of a slowdown: way too many records returned or a bad query execution plan. I would check the latter, i.e. verify what actual query is executed and if your DB lets you inspect the execution plan, try to find out what the bottleneck is. Chances are an index or two, placed smartly, would improve the execution time.

Comment: include the sql that you would write to get this.... you will find that this is generating something completely different. so I suggets you download linqpad and learn how to do some simple joins and then go from there.

Comment: What version of EF?